# What is this blank area in tableview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

There is a large blank area at the top of my tableview. I can scroll the rows up into this area. I'm not sure what is causing it.

[image]

Here's the tableview in Xcode:

[image]

Tableview row height is set to 44, which it looks like that is being enforced. I don't have a custom cell row height. Any ideas what could be causing this? I'd like the rows to go to the top of the tableview.

Comment: Can you fill some data to your cell and check from where the actual cell starts, I think that empty space is one of your tableview cell, it can be a header, it can happen because of incorrect auto layout constraints. Several possibilities.

Comment: The actual data starts right below the white area.

Comment: Need more details for finding the issue, did you set any auto-layout constraint for your tableview ? Are your overriding the heightforrowatindexpath ? Are you setting any header for your sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets.

Comment: Nice! I haven't seen this technique before but also have run into this problem. Do you know how this could have happened?

Comment: From @FouZ's answer (now deleted), I'm guessing the nav bar had something to do with it.

Comment: basically you have to fill the table to top edge of window not bottom of nav bar